# .Net 6 Unable to resolve service for type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet

Tags: c#, api, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, invalidoperationexception

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1[Entities.Product]' while attempting to activate 'Drin.Data.Repositories.GenericRepository`1[Entities.Product]'.

I getting this error while try to execute controller method

```
public class SampleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SampleDbContext(DbContextOptions<SampleDbContext> options) : base(options) {
        
    }

    public DbSet<Category>  Category { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductFeature> ProductFeature { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());     

        builder.Entity<ProductFeature>().HasData(
            new ProductFeature { Id = 1, Colour = "Black", Weight = 40, ProductId = 1 },
            new ProductFeature { Id = 2, Colour = "Blue", Weight = 10, ProductId = 2 });


        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Program.cs code file like that

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IService<>), typeof(Service<>));
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MapProfile));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<SampleDbContext>(x =>
{
    x.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection"), options =>
    {
        options.MigrationsAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SampleDbContext)).GetName().Name);
    });
});
```

GenericRepository Like that also:

```
    public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly SampleDbContext context;
        private readonly DbSet<T> dbSet;

        public GenericRepository(SampleDbContext context, DbSet<T> dbSet)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();
        }

        public async Task AddAsync(T entity)
        {
            await dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
        } 
}
```

Comment: Please share the code, cause issue should be there, not in the swagger ui.

Comment: Please do not share the code as images, share it as text. Also it is context class, not repository one which causes the problem.

Comment: Sory I will share as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are injecting `DbSet<Product>` into your repository. Usual approach is to register context only in the DI with `AddDbContext` or `AddDbContextFactory` and resolve context in the repository:

```cs
public class SomeClassDependingOnDb
{
    private readonly SomeAppDbContext _context;
    public class SomeClassDependingOnDb(SomeAppDbContext context) => _context = context;
    ... 
}
```

Then you can use it to access specific `DbSet` via generic type via [`Set<TEntity>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-6.0) method - `_context.Set<TEntity>` (if holding method/type is generic of `TEntity`).

See more in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/):

1. [DbContext Lifetime, Configuration, and Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/)
2. [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

**UPD**

Taking in account everything written earlier you repo should look like this (remove the `DbSet<T> dbSet` parameter):

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly SampleDbContext context;
    private readonly DbSet<T> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(SampleDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(T entity)
    {
        await dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you review again?

Comment: @mach my answer still holds, but please see the update.